# Configuring Static Analysis to Detect insecure MVC Routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, static-analysis

I want to create a static analysis code rule such that any controller's method must either inherit AllowAnonymous OR Authorize, or have an explicit AllowAnonymous OR Authorize attribute - so that every action has been addressed explicitly one way or the other.

Any guidance on how to do this - OR if you see a better solution - would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended approach is to register the `AuthorizeAttribute` globally. This effectively means none of your action methods can be accessed by default without logging in.

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        // Enable white-list security
        filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```

And in Global.asax.cs

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

        // Register global filters
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
    }
}
```

This will effectively enable 'white list' security, meaning you will have to explicitly opt out of the security scheme with the `AllowAnonymous` attribute on the methods that the public should see (such as the home page).

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

        return View();
    }
}
```

Note that you can also opt out of white list security at the controller level, which will make all methods of the HomeController anonymous by default.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I've implemented this, but I want to force the developer to explicitly identify each attribute as either requiring a login or not.

Comment: I see. Perhaps a better approach would be to make a unit test to verify this, and setup your build process to fail if one is missing. That will definitely force the matter.

Comment: Yeah, that's not a bad idea, but I'd like to come up with a ruleset that I could apply to all of our MVC projects. A Unit Test would be bound to the specific project, and would have to be rewritten for every project. I think that's my plan B, though.

Comment: This is all for Jenkins, BTW. I want to break the build if certain rules are not followed.